# Is their a simple way to detect if the actual time is near a specific time?

Tags: actionscript-3, time

I've got an AS3 code that calculate and displays 4 tides. 
Example :

High 1 = 13:20

High 2 = 23:30

Low 1 = 05:30

Low 2 = 16:20

In code, I'm not gonna put here the calculation as it's too long and not necessary for this problem, but the variables are :

```
var $pmm:String;
var $pms:String;
var $bmm:String;
var $bms:String;

High 1 = $pmm

High 2 = $pms

Low 1 = $bmm

Low 2 = $bms
```

The app also displays the actual time

```
var my_timer:Timer=new Timer(1000);
my_timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, onTimer);
my_timer.start(); 

function onTimer(e:TimerEvent):void {
now = new Date();
trace(now.hours + ":" + now.minutes);
}

actual_time.text=now.hours + ":" + now.minutes;
```

Is there a simple way to detect if `now.hours` is closest to `$pmm`, `$pms`, `$bmm` or `$bms` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this would be the best method, but I would take the difference between the now time and the tide times and push it into an array like so:

```
var tideArray = new Array();
tideArray.push({tide:"pmm", difference: 3});
tideArray.push({tide:"pms", difference: 5});
tideArray.push({tide:"bmm", difference: 0});
tideArray.push({tide:"bms", difference: 8});

tideArray.sortOn("difference", Array.NUMERIC);
trace(tideArray[0].tide);
```

The trace of the first element would return the lowest difference in time, which in this case would be bmm.

Comment: Thx ! So the `difference` can be `now.hour` (a date) and `"pmm"` could be equal to my variable `$pmm` ? 

Sorry, but it's the first time that I see this "difference" code. Very interesting !

Comment: Hmm I think your code is wrong or I didn't understand it. It seems that you are writing the `difference` in advance and it's just returning the lowest  `difference`. In my question, the tides (pmm, pms, bmm and bms) are hours. Different everyday.

Comment: I might be a little off with what you were asking but if pmm occurs at 13:20 you could just input

tideArray.push({tide:"pmm", difference: Math.abs(13 - now.getHours())});

13 being the hour that the pmm tide occurs

then just change it accordingly for the other tides

Comment: Ok, so if the variables change you could just input a variable representing the hour of the day for the tide like 

tideArray.push({tide:"pmm", difference: Math.abs(pmmHour - now.getHours())});

Comment: I think I've, maybe, found a way. Could you just telle me how to trace the closest number to 0 in the array please ? because, `difference` in my code can be a negative number. So, If I have `-7` `-1` `5` and `10` it will choose `-7` and I'd like to chose the closest to 0

Comment: I would do Math.abs(VALUE); to get the absolute value of the negative number because leaving it as a negative shouldn't matter.